# Simple if statement to create a new variable

Tags: r

Using R, I need to create a variable whose value will be:
 "*" if another variable's value is smaller than a fixed value
 "ns" if the same variable's value  is equal to or greater than a fixed value

In SAS, this would be:

```
if lifeExp < 30  then x1="* ";
if lifeExp => 30 then x1="ns";
```

In R, I imagine it would be something like this:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gapminder)
gapminder %>%
   mutate(x1 = case_when(lifeExp < 30) ~"*")
   x1= case_when(lifeExp=> 30)~"ns")  -> new_data
```

I get an errror message:

```
+   mutate(x1 = case_when(lifeExp < 30) ~"*")
Error: Column `x1` is of unsupported type quoted call
> x1= case_when(lifeExp=> 30)~"ns")  -> new_data
Error: unexpected '>' in "x1= case_when(lifeExp=>"
```

Comment: I agree with @joran, but the proper syntax for the other option would be `mutate(x1 = case_when(lifeExp < 30 ~ "*", lifeExp >= 30 ~ "ns"))` or, more succinct and robust: `mutate(x1 = case_when(lifeExp < 30 ~ "*", TRUE ~ "ns"))`.

Comment: Thanks joran and r2evans.  I am going to use @r2evan 's solution, the second one.  Thanks.  One question, why the expression TRUE?  Intuitively, I expected something like "NOT TRUE".

Comment: May I also ask something similar -- if SAS:

if lifeExp = 0  then x1="group1";
if lifeExp >0 and lifeExp < 10 then x1="group2";
if lifeExp => 10 then x1="group3";

Comment: When none of the conditions are met, `case_when` returns `NA`. If you want to always return non-`NA`, then specify `TRUE~...`. If you read the docs on it, the function evaluates each LHS until the first `TRUE`, at which point it returns the applicable RHS, so if you get to the `TRUE ~ ...` it will always trigger. If you instead did `case_when(TRUE ~ 1,anything_else ~ 0)` it will *never* return anything other than 1.

Comment: The LHS of each argument can be anything that returns a `logical` vector (of the correct length), so `case_when(lifeExp <= 0 ~ "group1", lifeExp > 0 + lifeExp < 10 ~ "group2", TRUE ~ "group3")` works. Some notes: (1) with floating point (`1` as opposed to `1L`), you should never rely on tests of equality (`==`), instead going for tests of inequality (perhaps a difference within a tolerance, e.g., `lifeExp < 1e-8` never `lifeExp == 0`. (2) This might be more-easily handled with `cut(lifeExp, c(-1, 1e-8, 10, Inf), labels = FALSE)` which can be used to index on the vector `paste0("group",1:3)`.

Comment: By the way, while all these comments and the posted answer are ways to approach it, the reason you're getting an error is that you have misplaced closing parens and a missing comma: `mutate(x1 = case_when(lifeExp < 30 ~"*"),  x1= case_when(lifeExp=> 30~"ns"))`. Check that closely against the code you posted and you'll see the difference.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have your data stored in a dataframe. If you are working with vectors (so nothing inside tables), this will not work. However, you didn't specify your objects, so I am assuming you are working with a table of some sort.

Let your data be stored in a dataframe called `dt`. Here's two solutions:

```
# Base R solution:
dt$x1 <- ifelse(test = dt$lifeExp < 30, yes = "*", no = "")

# Data table solution
library(data.table)
dt <- as.data.table(dt)
dt[, x1 := ifelse(test = lifeExp < 3, yes = "*", no = "ns")]
```